# I cant figure out how to write this list to a csv file how i want it, python

Tags: python, csv, rows

This is my code:

```
geometries = [[a, b, c], [d, e, f]] #Note I have lists within a list, this is required

with open("./datafiles/" + name, 'wb') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL, lineterminator='\n')
        writer.writerow(geometries)
```

This code is meant to write the lists within geometries to a CSV file. The CSV file should look like this:

```
a, b, c

d, e, f
```

Instead I get a txt file that looks like this:

```
|['a', 'b', 'c']|,|['d','e','f']|
```

How do I remove these ( |  [ ]  '' ) from the text file and have it displayed as above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use [`.writerows()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows) not `writerow()`.

By using the correct function, it'll output your CSV file as you expect.

The issue you have with the lines showing on the same row in some editors is due to your [`lineterminator`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.lineterminator). You are setting it to `\n`, instead of the default `\r\n`

Comment: Ok ive done that and its removed the unnecessary (| [ ] '') but its still only writing to one line of the text file

Comment: You'll need to provide more information (like what, exactly, your `geometries` list of lists contains. When I make the variables in your example strings (`[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]`) it creates two rows as expected

Comment: After adding the lists to geomtries and using the code: print geometries, this is what is in geometries:

[['Origin', 'Right Angled', 'P1 Easting', 'P1 Northing', 'Side P1P2', 'Angle opposite side P1P2', 'P2 Easting', 'P2 Northing', 'Side P2P3', 'Angle opposite side P2P3', 'P3 Easting', 'P3 Northing', 'Side P3P1', 'Angle opposite side P3P1'], ['--', '--', 1.0, 2.0, 2.8284271247461903, 0.0, 3.0, 4.0, 2.8284271247461903, 0.0, 5.0, 6.0, 5.656854249492381, 180.0]]

Comment: If I open the csv txt file in notepad++ it displays the information on seperate rows, if I display symbols I get LF at then end of each line. 

Using a supplied CSV file (rows are displayed properly), at the end of each line should be CR and LF (Carriage Return, Line Feed). I am missing the CR.

It's not an issue if I use notepad++ but if I want to open it with regular notepad thats when everything is on one row.

Comment: Your `lineterminator` is set to `\n` instead of the default `\r\n`

Comment: I have solve the issue by amending lineterminator to \r\n

Comment: Thanks andy, I solved it just before you posted haha :)

Answer (score 1):

[`.writerow()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerow) expects a flat list as a parameter. To write a list of rows at once use [`.writerows()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows):

```
geometries = [[a, b, c], [d, e, f]] 

with open("./datafiles/" + name, 'wb') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|',
                        quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL, lineterminator='\n')
    writer.writerows(geometries)
```

Comment: Wow i was missing an s >.>

Ok ive done that and its removed the unnecessary (|  [  ]  '') but its still only writing to one line of the text file